# Windows batch - Convert Mapped Drive Path ( with spaces ) to short path

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, batch-processing

I'm writing some code in windows batch and I have the following question:
Is there a way to convert a mapped drive path that has spaces in it (eg: E:\test\some text\dir1) to a path that has no space? Or how to deal with paths that have spaces in them?
PS : double quotes won't do the trick either.

The space in the paths are currently messing up my batch script.

Comment: If you remove the spaces, then it's not the same path. Tell us more about what you are trying to do, show us your code, and tell us where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Explain why you think you cannot use quotes around the file name, and show your code. There is probably a syntax that will allow use of quotes.

Comment: Short file names may be disabled on an NTFS volume, so that is not a good general solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need These: ""

So your Path Needs to be: "E:\test\some text\dir1" and not E:\test\some text\dir1

Hope it helps...

greez Brian

Answer (score 0):

The short folder name is the first six non-space characters of your folder name followed by `~1`, so in your case, you would use `E:\test\somete~1\dir1`.

If there is more than one directory with the same first six characters, they will be listed as `~1`, `~2`, and so forth.

You can use `dir /X` to see what the short name of the folder you want will be.

Comment: There is no reliable formula for predicting the short name of a given file or folder. The answer depends on what files existed at the time the file/folder was created. Also, the alogorithm is undocumented.

Comment: This is only true if there are more than four files or folders with the same first six non-space characters. For fewer than four files or folders with the same first six characters, the `somete~1` convention will be consistent according to [How Windows Generates 8.3 File Names from Long File Names](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982).

Comment: The documentation is outdated and incomplete. Plus the problem is much more insidious than you realize. When the file was created, there could have been multiple existing files with the same first 6 characters, so the final number would not be 1. Then, when you later check, the other files might have been deleted. So you could have a short name ending in ~3, yet not have another ending ~1. You should never write code that relies on prediction of a short name. It is impossible to predict unless you know the full history of the folder contents, as well as the complete set of rules.

Comment: True, but couldn't he parse the output of `dir /x` and do a `find` for the folder he was looking for?

Comment: Absolutely, nothing wrong with that. It is just the statements about how the short names are generated that concern me. However, It is easier to use a FOR variable with the `~s` modifier to get the short file name.